# How i setup the Paypal Express with Paypal credit and Debit card option in checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, paypal-express, paypal-payflow-pro

I am facing issue from 1 month the Paypal express option is perfectly work, but the paypal credit and Debit card option not show in checkout page, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Which version you are using of Magento ?

Comment: 2.4.5-p1 @Dotsquares

Answer (score 0):

For Configure PayPal Express Checkout Payment Method Refer following Links

- https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-paypal-express-checkout-payment-method-magento-2.html
- https://www.javatpoint.com/paypal-setup-in-magento-2
- https://magefan.com/blog/configure-paypal-in-magento-2